# Show SQL data in android layout

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have a problem with the following issue:

I have build an Android app which saves data into a SQL database (SQLite). I managed so the current date, time and the category is saved down and shown in a different menu. Somehow I am not able to get the value saved down and shown in the other layout. The data should come from an EditText:  android:id="@+id/edit_betrag

The SQL column is defined like: public static final String BUDGET_BETRAG = "betrag";

and then should be shown in textView_betrag in the class BudgetRechnerAdapter respectively the other layout.

Can you please help me with this issue? Thanks a lot!!!

---

public class BudgetRechnerOpenHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String TAG = BudgetRechnerOpenHandler.class
        .getSimpleName();

// Name und Version der Datenbank
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "budgetrechner.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Name und Attribute der Tabelle "Budget"
public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String TABELLE_NAME_BUDGET = "budget";
public static final String BUDGET_ZEIT = "zeitStempel";
public static final String BUDGET_AUSGABENART = "ausgabenArt";
public static final String BUDGET_BETRAG = "betrag";

// Konstanten für die Stimmungen
public static final int BUDGET_ESSEN = 1;
public static final int BUDGET_GETRAENK = 2;
public static final int BUDGET_SONSTIGES = 3;


// Tabelle Budget anlegen
private static final String TABELLE_BUDGET_ERSTELLEN = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABELLE_NAME_BUDGET + " (" + _ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + BUDGET_ZEIT + " INTEGER, "
        + BUDGET_BETRAG + " INTEGER," + BUDGET_AUSGABENART + " INTEGER);";
// Tabelle Budget löschen
private static final String TABELLE_BUDGET_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
        + TABELLE_NAME_BUDGET;

BudgetRechnerOpenHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABELLE_BUDGET_ERSTELLEN);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrade der Datenbank von Version " + oldVersion + " zu "
            + newVersion + "; alle Daten werden gelöscht");
    db.execSQL(TABELLE_BUDGET_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insert(int art, String beschreibung, long zeit) {
    long rowId = -1;
    try {
        // Datenbank öffnen
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        // die zu speichernden Werte
        ContentValues wert = new ContentValues();
        wert.put(BUDGET_AUSGABENART, art);
        wert.put(BUDGET_BETRAG, beschreibung);
        wert.put(BUDGET_ZEIT, zeit);
        // in die Tabelle Budget einfügen
        rowId = db.insert(TABELLE_NAME_BUDGET, null, wert);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "insert()", e);
    } finally {
        Log.d(TAG, "insert(): rowId=" + rowId);
    }
}

public Cursor query() {
    // ggf. Datenbank öffnen
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABELLE_NAME_BUDGET, null, null, null, null, null,
            BUDGET_ZEIT + " DESC"
        );
}

public void update(long id, int ausgabe_art_zahl) {
    // ggf. Datenbank öffnen
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BUDGET_AUSGABENART, ausgabe_art_zahl);
    int numUpdated = db.update(TABELLE_NAME_BUDGET, values, _ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { Long.toString(id) });
    Log.d(TAG, "update(): id=" + id + " -> " + numUpdated);
}

public void delete(long id) {
    // ggf. Datenbank öffnen
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    int numDeleted = db.delete(TABELLE_NAME_BUDGET, _ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { Long.toString(id) });
    Log.d(TAG, "delete(): id=" + id + " -> " + numDeleted);
}
```

}

---

public class BudgetRechnerAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
private final Date datum;

private static final DateFormat DF_DATE = SimpleDateFormat
        .getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
private static final DateFormat DF_TIME = SimpleDateFormat
        .getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

private Integer betrag;

private static final Integer DF_BETRAG = R.id.edit_betrag;
private LayoutInflater inflator;
private int ciAusgabenArt, ciZeit, ciBetrag;

public BudgetRechnerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    datum = new Date();
    betrag = null;
    inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ciAusgabenArt = c.getColumnIndex(BudgetRechnerOpenHandler.BUDGET_AUSGABENART);
    ciZeit = c.getColumnIndex(BudgetRechnerOpenHandler.BUDGET_ZEIT);
    ciBetrag = c.getColumnIndex(BudgetRechnerOpenHandler.BUDGET_BETRAG);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    int art = cursor.getInt(ciAusgabenArt);
    TextView textView_art = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
    if (art == BudgetRechnerOpenHandler.BUDGET_ESSEN) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bild_essen);
        textView_art.setText("Essen");
    } else if (art == BudgetRechnerOpenHandler.BUDGET_GETRAENK) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bild_getraenk);
        textView_art.setText("Getränk");
    } else {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bild_sonstiges);
        textView_art.setText("Sonstiges");
    }
    TextView textView_Datum = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView textView_Zeit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    TextView textView_betrag = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text4);


    long zeitStempel = cursor.getLong(ciZeit);
    datum.setTime(zeitStempel);
    textView_Datum.setText(DF_DATE.format(datum));
    textView_Zeit.setText(DF_TIME.format(datum));
    textView_betrag.setText(DF_BETRAG.toString());

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflator.inflate(R.layout.verlauf, null);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you include the Logcat that appears when you try to do it? Could you also show how you call the adapter (specially how you call the cursor in)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The log cat only shows insert(): rowId=6

Comment: And a GetMotionRecognitionManager

Comment: The weird thing is, it is working - but the list shows me a strange number: 2131165185, and not the number I was typing in

Comment: I think your code for the SQlite database is ok. The problem is likely to be in how the data is introduce to your method insert in the database. Have you checked that?

Comment: So you guess that is wrong? I can't see the problem with this coding... 

BudgetRechnerAdapter
private static final Integer DF_BETRAG = R.id.edit_betrag;
TextView textView_betrag = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text4);
textView_betrag.setText(DF_BETRAG.toString());

Comment: What I think might be the problem is how the data is introduced, have you checked if the data acutally in the database is 2131165185? You can debug the code and check if the number that is transferred to the insert method is actually that odd number.

Comment: Any idea how I can check that as I can't see it in the log or anywhere else....

Comment: Um... you should be able to use LogCat, if you are developing in eclipse you shall be able to see it in the specific window, if not you can extract it by using "abd logcat".